# How to count Number Of Occurences and Use it for Line Chart in R

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2, data-visualization, linechart

so for example i got this dataframe

| Brand | owner | Period |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Adidas | andy | May 2018 |
| Nike | diana | June 2019 |
| Adidas | rose | August 2019 |
| Nike | sara | July 2020 |
| Puma | laura | March 2020 |
| Joma | harry | April 2018 |
| Adidas | jon | May 2018 |
| Diadora | keith | June 2021 |

how do i count the number of occurences of the brand and use it as a y axis, period for x axis (yearmon num), and group by owner to make a chart line?

Comment: Welcome to SO. It is helpful if you can make your question reproducible. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example  and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, the number of obs is too little to run it properly. But transform `Period` to a date format for proper display (maybe use `lubridate` or `zoo` as package). Then run the following:

```
library(ggplot2)

df %>%
  group_by(Brand, owner, Period) %>%
  add_count() %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  ggplot(aes(Period, n, group=owner, col=owner) +
  geom_line()
```

Comment: what if i want to group it by brand and use the number of occurrence as the y axis, and the period( yearmon) as the x axis?

Comment: Try `df %>% group_by(Brand, Period) %>% add_count() %>% ungroup() %>% ggplot(aes(Period, n)) + geom_line()`. Then, of course, no grouping by `owner` obtains. Just one remark: Be so kind to accept my post as answer to your question, if it answers your questions. Thanks!